# Exception handling when the input link doesn't have the appropriate form

Tags: python, xml, exception, beautifulsoup

for instance, i have a list of links like this:

```
linklists = ['www.right1.com', www.right2.com', 'www.wrong.com', 'www.right3.com']
```

and the form of each right1,right2 and right3's html is:

```
<html>
<p>
hi
</p>
<strong>
hello
</strong>
</html>
```

and the form of www.wrong.com html is(actual html is much more complicated):

```
<html>
<p>
hi
</p>
</html>
```

and i'm using a code like this:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
stronglist=[]
for httplink in linklists:  
    url = httplink
    page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        html = page.read()
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    findstrong = soup.findAll("strong")
    findstrong = str(findstrong)
    findstrong = re.sub(r'\[|\]|\s*<[^>]*>\s*', '', findstrong)        #remove tag
    stronglist.append(findstrong)
```

what i want to do is:

1. get through html links from the list `'linklists'`
2. find data between `<strong>`
3. add them to list `'stronglist'`

but the problem is:
there is a wrong link (`www.wrong.com`) that has no .
then the code says error...

what i want is an exception handling(or something else) that if the link doesn't have 'strong' field(it has error), i want the code to add the string 'null' to the stronglist since it can't get data from the link.

i have been using 'if to solve this but it's a bit hard for me

any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not going to capitalize all your `i`s for you, do that by yourself please.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use exception handling. Just identify when the findAll method returns an empty list and deal with that.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
strong_list=[]
for url in link_list:  
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())
    strong_tags = soup.findAll("strong")
    if not strong_tags:
        strong_list.append('null')
        continue
    for strong_tag in strong_tags:
        strong_list.append(strong_tag.text)
```

Comment: No problem! It's always nice to accept the answer as well as just vote it up. BTW, if you did want to catch the exception then you might want to tell us what the exception being raised is and what line is causing it. Cheers